# How to change text on buttonClick in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I have a problem that there is a lot of text which user has to go through. Is there a possible way to store all these possible text changes in enum or array and then show them to user.
Or should I restrict myself to simple hard typing techniques?

Comment: Example what u need to do? show them where? the buttonClick where does it fit in your title?

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array of strings and integer variable named index so that then increase the index and modify current text by getting the the string of the current index on the array.

There you have an example of course you need to work on this and setup this by yourself by populating the array and on click increase the currentIndex so that then you can set the UI text to your current string.

Example:

```
int currentIndex = 0;
string[] captions = new string[5];
Text textHolder;

currentIndex++;
textHolder.Text = captions[currentIndex];
```